# undo and redo for jquery drag and drop clone

Tags: jquery

I am working on a flowchart editor where users can drag and flowchart icons. I have used JqueryUI drag and drop and clone for this.
I need to integrate **undo and redo** for this flowchart editor.
I tried with undomanager js, its does not suits for drag, drop and clone.
Please suggest me any alternate solution.

Thanks